# Create Object in Object

Tags: javascript

I'm confuse the way how Google Chrome developer tool console is displaying if the (A) is the actual object created in the loop, why are the (B) contains 3 objects?

Does it means (A) will contain 3 objects?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/LygmkgLm/

```
var test={}
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
  test[i]={}
  test[i].y="111"
console.log("test",test)
}
```

[image]

Comment: may be it's showing the final value of result...

Comment: Hover or click on the `[i]` in the console next to the output and you will know why.

Comment: Chrome shows final value of variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the console output. It correctly and and as expected shows the increasing contents of the object within the loop, hence the 1, 2 and 3 members in the output. At the end however the variable 'test' is the fully filled object, and when you expand the first line it shows the contents *at the time of expansion*. Being the fully filled object with 3 children.

Your confusion arises from the fact that the logging does not store the state of the object at logging time.

Comment: You explained it simply, though tried hard to put my words simple in answer. :) But I was trying to explain same point.

Comment: Yeah, your explanation makes it easier to digest. It felt like a realtime logging but is simply more like a simulator, that's really efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome console shows the final object in console. It shows whatever the values have gone through the object. So in console first it will show you

```
test Object {0: Object}
```

But when you extend, it will have three object which has passed through it.

```
test Object {0: Object}0: Object1: Object2: Object__proto__: Object
```

One thing to note that, at first iteration of the loop, you may see three object in console but only one object i.e.

```
test Object {0: Object}
```

is actually accessible. If you want to check actual state of object in each iteration, you have to clone it like below

```
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, test);
```

Here is the fiddle which will give you an idea of my points https://jsfiddle.net/qtdurtzc/